# alter rails' (formtastic's) input buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

what can I do on application level (without touching individual views), so that

```
= f.submit('Hello World')
```

renders as a

```
<button type="submit"/>Hello World</button>
```

and not as input type='submit'